# Mongoose Promise not populating in script

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an api server and some script jobs. They are using the same function to pull a roster using mongoose and populate the players in the roster. 
On the api server, this function is called normally. Using the script, it doesn't.

API example

```
function getRoster(id) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    Roster.find({_id:id}, 'playerRoster userId tournamentId').populate('playerRoster').exec(
        function(err, roster) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.resolve(err);
            }
            deferred.resolve(roster[0]);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
api.post('/get_roster', function(req, res) {
        // get tournament
        var id = req.body._id;
        var playerId = req.body.playerId;
        getRoster(id).then(function(data) {
            var roster=data;
            res.json(roster);
        });
    });
```

Script

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    this.getRoster=function(id) {
            //return Roster.find({_id:id}, 'playerRoster userId tournamentId').exec( - THIS RETURNS
            return Roster.find({_id:id}, 'playerRoster userId tournamentId').populate('playerRoster').exec(
                function(err, roster) {
                    if (err) {
                        return err;
                    }
                    console.log('roster[0]',roster);
                    return roster[0];
                });
        }

   this.tallyPoints = function(tournamentPlayer,sportsPlayers) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var totalPoints =0;
        console.log("tallyPoints 0 ",tournamentPlayer);
        var rosterId = tournamentPlayer.player.roster[0];
        console.log("tallyPoints 1 ",rosterId);
        this.getRoster(rosterId).then(function(roster2){
            console.log("tallyPoints 2 ",roster2);
            ...
            deferred.resolve(totalPoints);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return this;

};
```

In the script, neither logging for the roster[0] or tallyPoints 2 lines print, but there is no error either.

Why doesn't Roster.find return when I add populate? The only thing I can imagine is because playerRoster collection has 2000 records searching for ~10 and it hits some timeout that isn't being caught.

Any suggestion to clean it up is also appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The suggestion is to clean up control flow before moving any further. You never need Q.defer with Mongoose. It already returns promises. This is promise construction antipattern. `if (err) {
                return err;
            }` - this is wrong, the promise should be rejected, this is one of many reasons why it's an antipattern.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the err. The api works though. So completely remove deferred from getRoster? Then I can't call then on getRoster

Comment: I made an update to the script function based on your suggestion, but still not returning when I add populate

Comment: There are still problems. I provided an example how it should be done. It's unclear what is exact problem in your case, but there could be an error and you never know about it because errors aren't handled.

Answer (score 0):

Moongoose supports promises for a long time. It's unsuitable to use callback-based Mongoose API where promises are desirable and the use of `Q.defer` with existing promises is known as Deferred antipattern (similarly, `new Promise` results in promise construction antipattern).

In its current state `getRoster` doesn't return a promise and doesn't handle errors correctly.

```
function getRoster(id) {
    return Roster.find({_id:id}, 'playerRoster userId tournamentId').populate('playerRoster').exec()
    .then(roster => roster[0]);
}

api.post('/get_roster', function(req, res) {
    // get tournament
    var id = req.body._id;
    var playerId = req.body.playerId;
    getRoster(id)
    .then(function(data) {
        var roster=data;
        res.json(roster);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle error
    });
});
```

Considering that only `roster[0]` is used, it likely should be changed to `Roster.findOne`.

It doesn't matter whether `getRoster` is used in Express route or elsewhere, it should work. It's unknown how `module.exports = function(config) {...}` module is used, but `this` may refer to wrong context if it isn't used as class. If `getRoster` and `tallyPoints` don't use `config`, they shouldn't reside inside this function.